# WebAPI- How to implement layers?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api

This is my simple `customer` controller in `Web API`.

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    BusinessLayer.ICustomerRepositary CustomerRepositary;

    public CustomerDTO Get()
    {
        BusinessLayer.Customer customer = CustomerRepositary.GetCustomers();

        // Map customer to customerDTO

        return customerDTO;
    }
}
```

***My project Oganization:***

**BusinessLayer** --> Models (Customer.cs), CustomerRepositary, ICustomerRepositary

**APILayer**      --> DTOs (CustomerDTO.cs), CustomerController

[image]

My question is:

1. Is `tightly coupling the business layer with the API` layer, a good idea ?
2. Are there any other patterns to be implemented here?
3. When I am implementing unit tests, the unit tests contain the references of business layer. Is this design a correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most things in software, it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

However, typically, classes that are created at a higher layer, can depend on classes from a lower layer.  But not the other way around.

So, I don't see anything wrong with the direction that your code is moving in.

When writing tests for the `CustomerController`, you will be referencing `BusinessLayer` classes.  However, when writing tests for the `BusinessLayer` classes, you would *not* expect to be referencing the `WebAPIApplication` classes.

Comment: Again it depends on if you are moving towards a 3-tier architecture or more of an [Onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/).  At the beginning, I think it is fine that have your repositories inside the business layer.  If you have multiple implementations of the repo, you may want to only keep the interface in the bus layer (in the future).

Comment: Simple yet great explanation. Thanks :)